# No connection string named '<EF connection string>' could be found in the application config file - error - .Net core 2.2 with .NET 4.6 EF

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string, configuration-files, asp.net-4.6

I'm trying to add **.NET 4.6.1 class library project** which using **Entity-Framework 6** as DAL layer into a solution which is running under **.Net Core 2.2** startup project (**Web-Api**).
The EF project was using a different "old" (.NET Framework 4.6.1 class library) web-api project as end points, but now I want to gather all the end-points under one project.

The problem is that the running context is **.NET Core 2.2** which use **appsettings.json** as configuration file, so I copied the **ConnectionsStrings** details from the "old" XML configuration into the appsettings.json file, but it seems like the EF can't read connection strings (which used to be in a **web.config XML** file when used the "old" **.net 4.2 web-api project**) from the **appsettings.json** file.

- I'd rather continue working with the current EF and not change it to **EF .Core**

The error I'm getting is:
"No connection string named '' could be found in the application config file"

How can I solve it ?

Is there a reason for .Net core not "naturally" working with EF 6 when on .NET 4.6 ?

This is my appsettings.json file (Ignore types - it is not copy-paste but free hand copying):

```
"ConnectionStrings":
{
    "MyMainDBEntities": {
        "ConnectionString": "metadata=res:...",
        "providerName": "system.Data.EntityClient"
    }
}
```

Comment: EF6 does not know how to read settings from json files.

Comment: Also, loading .net 4.x libraries from .NET Core is not supported, and .NET Core 2.2 is out of support.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is no real option other that using the EF Core - this is how I fixed the problem